# How to use CSS-only for cluster icons for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

My goal is to have CSS-*only* icons for my Google Maps marker clusters. I have seen in the documentation's "advanced example" ([link](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/examples/advanced_example.html)) that CSS-only icons are possible. However, I have been unable to translate this example into my own project.

I have attempted to build a [JSFiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/GoOutside/k6av7n32/4/), though I can not seem to initialize the map through JSFiddle due to API restrictions. When I run the code on my site, it adds numbers to the map, but no icons, as seen below.

[image]

I created some styles

```
  var styles = [{
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      className: "custom-clustericon-1",
    },
    {
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      className: "custom-clustericon-2",
    },
    {
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      className: "custom-clustericon-3",
    },
  ];
```

And I have attempted to initialize like this:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {
                styles: styles,
                clusterClass: "custom-clustericon", 
            });
```

Where am I missing the mark here? I'd like to have marker icons exactly like the ones in the "[advanced example](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/examples/advanced_example.html)", but I'm at a loss. I have searched *extensively* online for examples of css-*only* icons but could not find any standalone examples. Your help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of the `MarkerClusterer` library.

Use this one:

```
<script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7bsdor1w/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function map_initialize() {
  var mapoptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true
  };
  var styles = [{
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      className: "custom-clustericon-1",
    },
    {
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      className: "custom-clustericon-2",
    },
    {
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      className: "custom-clustericon-3",
    },
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdivbig"),
    mapoptions);
  var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    bounds.extend(location);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infoWin.setContent(location.info);
      infoWin.open(map, marker);
    })
    return marker;
  });
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    styles: styles,
    clusterClass: "custom-clustericon",
  });
}
var locations = [{
    lat: 45.4208,
    lng: -123.8,
    info: 'Location 1'
  },
  {
    lat: 47.6117,
    lng: -122.345,
    info: 'Location 2'
  },
  {
    lat: 47.6308,
    lng: -122.375,
    info: 'Location 3'
  }
]
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#mapdivbig {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#mapdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.custom-clustericon {
  background: var(--cluster-color);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-clustericon::before,
.custom-clustericon::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: var(--cluster-color);
  opacity: 0.2;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.custom-clustericon::before {
  padding: 7px;
}

.custom-clustericon::after {
  padding: 14px;
}

.custom-clustericon-1 {
  --cluster-color: #00a2d3;
}

.custom-clustericon-2 {
  --cluster-color: #ff9b00;
}

.custom-clustericon-3 {
  --cluster-color: #ff6969;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Marker Clustering</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=map_initialize" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapdivbig"></div>
</body>

</html>
```